# IdentityServer4 w/ Vue SPA - Silent Renew to External OIDC Provider

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have an Asp.Net Core IdentityServer4 instance securing an API that is fronted by a Vue.js SPA (using oidc-client).  The IS4 server is setup to manage "local" account itself for my companies users, but we also have an external OIDC provider setup for a trusted partner that allows their users to access our site using their single sign-on server (OIDC identity server). The partner's portal has a link to our app, so if they are already authenticated by their own OIDC server, then no additional login prompt is displayed.

Overall, this process works.  I can login "locally" (an account that is only on our identity server), or use the external OIDC provider that authenticates the user and goes through the auto-provisioning on our local IS4 server.  The Vue app has its tokens and silent refresh is enabled, which keeps the user's credentials updated against our IS4 server.

However, if a user from our partner comes to our app, spends some time there, and then returns to their own portal via a link on our site, it's likely that their access will have timed out and they see their own SSO login again.  This is because the silent refresh on our site is only refreshing our local IdentityServer4 credentials.

Is it possible to somehow maintain BOTH "sessions" while the partner user is on our site?  Silently refreshing both our IS4 token and their OIDC SSO credentials?